# Show values on specific coordinates on top of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image wherein I am adding multiple marker pins. And I am saving the position (x and y coordinates) of those to a database later.

Here is my code till now:
https://jsfiddle.net/at3wsepm/7/

Coordinates along with the pin names are saved to database  once user clicks the save button.

```
 _this.position.x = _this.element.position().left;
 _this.position.y = _this.element.position().top;
```

What I need is, when user reloads the page, I want to retrieve the positions of those markers from my database and then position it again on the same image. I can do the retrieval using PHP and get the pins and their coordinates as JSON- but how can I position them again on the image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on how exactly you're saving and retrieving the data, but assuming you're able to get the X and Y coordinates from the database back into the JavaScript, you then need to set the `left` and `top` attributes via [**`.css`**](http://api.jquery.com/css/). Note that you'll also need to set a [**`position`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) other than `static` in order for this to work.

```
$("#carea").append(elem.css({
  position: "relative", // `left` and `top` require a `position` other than `static`
  left: databaseX, // The pin's X coordinate in the database
  top: databaseY // The pin's Y coordinate in the database
}));
```

This will add the pin to the background at the position specified by the database values, as can be seen [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/yha3kv0n/).

Note that this adds a pin at the position specified relative to the top-left of the map element **when the page loads**; if the coordinates specified are outside the dimensions of the map, they will appear outside that element; the map won't hide them within its scroll.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I'm getting the data as JSON in this format 
 [{"x":165,"y":100,"pin":"S27"},{"x":447,"y":215,"pin":"S16"},{"x":189,"y":336,"pin":"S17"}]  
I need to put the pin names (S27, S16, S17) on their specific coordinates.

Comment: tried iterating through the json using for loop and appended to 'carea' . But it's not getting positioned.
`
//axisData is my JSON data

for ( var key in axisData ) 
{
    var els= "<div>  <span  class='sname'>"+axisData[key].sensor+"</span> </div>";
 var element = $(els).addClass("sdetails");  
  
 
 $("#carea").append(element.css({
      left: axisData[key].x, // The pin's X coordinate in the database
      top: axisData[key].y // The pin's Y coordinate in the database
}));
 `
 
 }

Comment: Ahh! My apologies; I forgot to add a position to the elements. They're getting the styles added correctly, but not **positioned**. Simply adding `position: "relative"` will fix this for you, as can be seen [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/d1bemdL6/). I've updated the answer to cover that. Also, for what it's worth, your JSON appears to be **invalid** (at least as it is written in your comment). You can ensure that it's correct at [**JSONLint**](http://www.jsonlint.com) :)